# proof of a useful counting result in group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let G be a finite group, H a subgroup of G satisfying |G| |̸| [G : H]!. Prove there exists a normal subgroup N of G satisfying 1 < N ⊂ H.

maybe the General Cayley's Theorem works. I am not sure. It seems that it requires a complicated proof. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the action of $G$ on the left cosets of $H$. This action affords a homomorphism from $G$ to the symmetric group of order $[G:H]!$. The kernel of this homomorphism is called the core of $H$ and is the largest normal subgroup contained by $H$.

Notice the order of the image of this homomorphism is a divisor of $[G:H]!$ Call this order $m$. So by the first isomorphism theorem $\frac{|G|}{|N|}=m$. We cannot have $|N|=1$ since otherwise $|G|=m$ and then the order of $G$ divides $[G:H]!$

Comment: i got a little bit stuck...how can you get |G|/|N|=m?

Comment: I defined n to be the order of the image of the homomorphism. By the first iso theorem G/N is isomorphic to the image of the morphism. Thus the order of G/N is n. The order of G/N is the order of G divided by the order of N.

Comment: I'm almost there. after you got |N| is not 1, so...?

Comment: So $N$ is non trivial. Since $N$ is kernel $N$ is normal, and it is in $H$. So it is what you wanted.